# ELIFECYCLE after npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I tried to use one of my Angular apps on my laptop.
But when I use `npm start`, I have the following message:

```
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (/home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:65:9)
    at /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:115:17
    at /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:314:6
    at /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:20:22
    at /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
```

Then this is my log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~prestart: jh-kanban@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: jh-kanban@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: CWD: /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular
10 silly lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jh-kanban@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: jh-kanban@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid jh-kanban@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/josh/Bureau/Perso/Projets/TasksWatcher/Angular
16 verbose Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.13.1
19 verbose npm  v6.12.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error jh-kanban@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the jh-kanban@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've searched many solutions on differents websites (including stackoverflow) and I tried these steps:

- run `npm cache clean --force`
- delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- run `npm install`
- re-run `npm start`

But it doesn't work.

I also tried to completely reinstall NodeJS and Angular CLI but nothing has changed.

Comment: Why are you not using AngularCLI?

Comment: "I also tried to completely reinstall NodeJS and Angular CLI but nothing has changed." I put this here....just in case

Comment: What happens if you use `ng serve`?

Comment: Did you (or somebody else) recently updated one of the dependencies?
Are there any errors or warnings when running `npm install` or `npm start`?

Comment: I have the same problem with `ng serve` @tobias .
@DanielHabenicht I didn't update anything.
Everything is good when I run `npm install`, but I had the problem described in my request if I run `npm start`.

Comment: Try running the app on a different port e.g. `ng serve --port 4201`

Comment: I've finally decided to update dependencies, then it has solved my problem. Thanks !!